# Controlling hover label of data point in Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change tooltip text for google chart api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013053/how-to-change-tooltip-text-for-google-chart-api)

I am using Google Charts to create a line chart:
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html

I would like to control the text displayed when the user clicks or hovers over a datapoint. Currently the hover only shows the dataset name and value (same a Y-axis). I would like to display additional meta-data. Is this possible? Does someone have an example?

Comment: I would also like to do this, have you made any progress?

Comment: Same problem here, ¿Any update?

Comment: You can do it like this very easy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862538/1164342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do this by using the following code -

```
<code>
data.setFormattedValue(<your custom hover lable>);
</code>
```

Refer here:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable_setFormattedValue

Comment: This only changed the Axis Titles, not the data displayed in the hover box.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "tooltip" in the dataTable roles:

```
 data.addColumn('number', 'Abscisses');
 data.addColumn('number', 'Warior');
 data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'tooltip'});
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});

 data.addRow([2,3,4,'a']);
 data.addRow([3,4,2,'b']);
```

Refers to:[DataTable roles](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/roles.html)

Comment: However I have not figured out a way to add labels to the tooltip, like I want to show "battle:4 name: a"in the tooltip. I appreciate if Someone who worked out the way could help.

Comment: Linecharts only allow one column with the role `tooltip`. Also to get the title you could always do this: `data.addRow([2,3,'Battle: 4\n Name: a']);` If you are for-eaching over your data it would be easy to manipulate the string you wanted to go to the tooltip.